# Blocking MPI calls

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

When using blocking communication in MPI, does blocking mean that no other processes can communicate a message until the first message is completed?

For example, if process 1 is sending to process 2 on two different nodes, could processes 3 and 4 communicate at the same time or do they have to wait until the communication between 1 and 2 is completed?

Comment: This question is very hard to understand. Maybe you can add code to demonstrate your question.

Answer (score 2):

In point to point MPI communication other processes can do whatever they want including sending and receiving MPI messages.

The blocking only means that when you call the `MPI_Send` or `MPI_Recv`, the call to these procedures will only return when the operation has been finished and the sending / receiving buffer can be used again. This is onlly a local thing, it blocks the progress of the given process.

Non blocking means that the process continues with other statements even if the communication is not yet finished and the buffer should not be used for reading or writing.